Platform-independent push notifications for MAUI and/or browser-based applications
I am at the concept stage in developing a new application for use on a smartphone (Android or iOS) where all the real work is happening on the server. If deployed as a smartphone app, it would be done in MAUI, otherwise it would just be a browser app. The determining factor is push notifications. The application needs to deliver push notifications to a targeted device in near real-time (latency up to 1min could be tolerated but ideally no more than a few seconds). Notification delivery must occur regardless of app state on the device i.e. app should not have to be foregrounded/active/running, if implemented as a browser app, browser should not have to be running.
I am familiar with (and have implemented) a solution for Windows Phone using WNS, so have a good understanding of what's needed and possible within a (now obsolete) single-vender ecosystem, but now looking at current platforms in a mixed world. I'm aware of Azure Notification Hub and have seen mention of Firebase, but I'm not finding any clear "how-to" paths for either, not seen mention of any other options, nor seen any discussion of trade-offs between available options.
Can a purely browser-based app receive push notifications regardless of browser state i.e. do all modern smartphone browsers support "background" push notifications? If so, where can I find relevant documentation for how a device registers to receive notifications and how a server sends a notification to a target device?
If modern browsers do not support push notifications while inactive, my question turns to MAUI... Are Firebase and Azure Hub the only feasible options? For each, what does the MAUI app do to register for notification and what does the server do to deliver a notification?
I should note that the message recipient will only be a mobile device, never a desktop.

Talking strictly from a Android/iOS perspective here but there are inherently some issue that you will find with the requirements you have set out.

The application needs to deliver push notifications to a targeted
device in near real-time (latency up to 1min could be tolerated but
ideally no more than a few seconds)

Neither Android nor iOS ever guarantee delivery of push notifications, they state this in their TOS. Android specifically has issues where different device manufacturers will break push notifications where they will only get received while in foreground because they try to push overly aggressive battery optimizations. Android (probably iOS too) also can throttle your messages if you send too many and there is an upper limit on the number you can send a day as well as the type of notifications you send.
Strictly speaking about Firebase here there are some limitations for web, the browser needs the Push API support. On iOS the webpage needs to be added to the home screen and the notifications are always silent (ie no noise/vibration) according to the compatibility matrix. You can check the version compatibility here
I am not familiar with Azure Notification Hub but its going to work similar to Firebase probably since they both need to use internal system API's for push notifications to work on mobile devices.
You can find the Firebase documentation here

So for web, I assume you are saying that it goes beyond a couple of simple user instructions like "make sure your browser is up-to-date" and "be sure to tick the (whatever) box to allow notifications".

For Firebase at least yeah (Azure Notification Hub might be different you would have to read the documentation).

And for a MAUI app, the client side implementation (registration) would need to be hand-crafted separately for each platform and specific to the notification service i.e. there is no platform-neutral MAUI API to take care of any of the specifics?

I dont know if there is any MAUI api or not I and just speaking from the point of view of each OS
